# Issue with Date and time when work with other country like USA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time, datepicker, timezone

`I have date picker which is select Expiry date this is working fine for india but when i test this for USA location it working differently.`

****Problem is like ****
Suppose today is 28 December in india and according to indian timezon the current time is 7:00 pm and in USA it is 8:30 am. So When I select date in india it will show 28 December with current time but When I select date From USA at same time it will show me 27 December.
I dont know what's going wrong with this.
I also Provide you the code also.

## **This is my React project, and I am providing state, function which is handling the expiry date and input also**

```
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        selectedFile: null,
        DOCUMENT_EXPIRY_DATE: "",
        DOCUMENT_TYPE: "",
    });

    const handleExpiryDateChange = (e) => {
        const selectedDate = e.target.value;

        // Use moment to adjust the date to the user's time zone
        const userTimeZoneDate = moment(selectedDate)
            .tz(moment.tz.guess())
            .format("YYYY-MM-DD");

        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            DOCUMENT_EXPIRY_DATE: userTimeZoneDate,
        });
    




        <div className="row mb-2">
            <div className="form-group col-xl-12">
                 <label className="pb-2 fs-6 rounded p-2">Select Expiry Date </label>
                       <input
                          type="date"
                          className="form-control mb-2 pb-2 pt-2 form-control-2 rounded-0"
                          id="DOCUMENT_EXPIRY_DATE"
                          name=" DOCUMENT_EXPIRY_DATE"
                          onChange={handleExpiryDateChange}
                          value={formData.DOCUMENT_EXPIRY_DATE}
                          required
                       />
            </div>
       </div>
```

Actually i do not have any idea about but i think there is an date time issue i have to pick the global location according to the timezone.
Expectation is this i need a proper solution using js which is better fit for my code i want to store the local timezone of where the user is selecting the date picker(expiry date).